# AppleScript Transmit Script for uploading file to replace itself on web server

Tags: ftp, applescript

So I have this idea for a handy little AppleScript which in my opinion would be very handy in speeding up the process of uploading a local file, to its same location on the server.

In other words, you have to specify the home folder on the server and locally, but once that's finished, it would be nice to just press like "Command" + "Shift" "U" for upload or some other hot key combination not in use by OS X for uploading the currently selected file in the Finder.

I find myself needing to do this a lot, and it will save a lot of time!

Someone please tell me if there is an easier way to do this, but I think this will be a good learning experience on top of it all.

I need some help on how I should get started however..

Comment: well I think of lots of things to do but most importantly I don't think writing a script is the answer what kind of files are you uploading ?

Comment: Yeah, I guess a program is better.. Just HTML, CSS, JS and ASP files to a web server. For regular testing and deving purposes.  The only thing I don't want to have to build a GUI or anything like that.  I can set up the basics pretty quickly, really.

Answer (score 1):

1) the command line program curl can upload files. 2) if you have a file selected in a Finder window applescript can get the selection. Using those 2 ideas you can automate your task. I don't know the exact curl command but that should be easy to find using google. So you select a file in the Finder and then run the script. The script can be run with a keyboard shortcut as you mentioned or just put it in the Script menu and run it from there.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set selectedFile to item 1 of (get selection)
    set selectedFile to selectedFile as text
end tell

do shell script "curl -switchesToUpload " & quoted form of POSIX path of selectedFile
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) which is an ftp client you can set it up so when you double click a file on the server it opens it up in your favorite editor.( [textmate](http://macromates.com/) is my favorite.)  it atuomagiclly downloads and uploads when you save.

this seems like a much better solution to the problem

Comment: what did you end up doing here ?